# Trapezoid box width changes beyond bounds

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, miktex, tikz-styles

I have made a flowchart in Tikz, where for the trapezoid (in/output) box I used the following command:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
```

The problem here is, I think, the `text width` parameter, because if I remove that the `output` box (see pictures) is fine, but the lines on the `input` are not wide enough. I call the `output` trapezoid as follows:

```
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro3, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result};
```

Resulting in an overly wide trapezoid, well beyond the required minimum of 3cm.

Changing the command to

```
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro3, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result\\~};
```

i.e. adding a linebreak and a non-breaking space sets the width of the trapezoid correctly, but that now has a pointless empty line, which makes the text no longer vertically centred in the box.

How can I get this second trapezoid to be of the correct (3cm) width, without forcing an empty line into it?

MCVE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%% TIKZ OPTIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,draw=black, text width=2cm, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (in1) [io] {Input:\\ $dt,nt,nx$ (scalars);\\ $\vect{x},\vect{p}$ (vectors);\\ $\matr{p}$ (data)};
\node (out1) [io, below of=in1, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (in1) [io] {Input:\\ $dt,nt,nx$ (scalars);\\ $\vect{x},\vect{p}$ (vectors);\\ $\matr{p}$ (data)};
\node (out1) [io, below of=in1, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result\\~};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I copied most of the code of [this tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)%E2%80%94Creating_Flowcharts) and tried to adapt it to my needs.

[image]

I am using TeXStudio 2.12.4 on Windows 7 with PdfLaTeX.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.3.14)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `trapezium stretches=true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `trapezium stretches=true` (and use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%% TIKZ OPTIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=red!30},
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm,
draw=black, fill=blue!30,trapezium stretches=true}, %<- added
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text
centered,draw=black, text width=2cm, fill=green!30},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (in1) [io] {Input:\\ $dt,nt,nx$ (scalars);\\ $\vect{x},\vect{p}$ (vectors);\\ $\matr{p}$ (data)};
\node (out1) [io, below of=in1, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (in1) [io] {Input:\\ $dt,nt,nx$ (scalars);\\ $\vect{x},\vect{p}$ (vectors);\\ $\matr{p}$ (data)};
\node (out1) [io, below of=in1, yshift=-0.5cm, xshift=0.5] {Output result\\~};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Out of curiosity, why does this help, and why can't I set `streches` in the `\tikzstyle`, whereas it works in `\tikzset`? Basically I just followed [this tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)—Creating_Flowcharts) and adapted that to my needs

Comment: @Adriaan You can use `\tikzstyle`, i.e. `\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm,
draw=black, fill=blue!30,trapezium stretches=true]` works. However, it is recommended to switch to `\tikzset`.